# Retrieving a vector from one of its permutations in R-software

Tags: r, vector, combinations, permutation

In R-software, suppose you have a vector N1 of length n.

```
n <- 10
N1 <- letters[rbinom(n, size = 20, prob = 0.5)]
names(N1) <- seq(n)
```

Suppose you have another vector N2 that is a permutation of the elements of N1

```
N2 <- sample(N1, size = n, replace = FALSE)
```

I was wondering if you could help me to find a function in R-software that receives N2 as input and obtains N1 as output, please. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Wait ... find a function that reverse-calculates the randomness of `sample`? (Perhaps there's a misunderstanding of "random" in the context of `sample`.) The only (mathematically justifiable) method that *could* give it to you is if you knew the state of the random seed before you took the `sample` and could regenerate the random indexing. Otherwise, I think the answer is very strongly "not possible".

Comment: Hi, @r2evans. Thanks for answering. I believe I did not explain clearly the problem. My problem is that I know N1 and N2. However, I would like to find an efficient algorithm that allows me to go from N2 to N1. I tried several methods with no success. I apologize if the question is basic.

Comment: Since your process allows duplication, there is uncertainy. Because you have uncertainty, either (a) you find *some* reverse-indexing, or (b) you calculate *all* reverse-indexing. (That is, if `N1` contains two `"j"`, then which goes where in `N2`?) Regardless, StackOverflow is not a "code this for me" environment, we are here to help you fix problems with code that you have already written or attempted. What have you tried?

Comment: If you have N1 and N2, why do you need a function that takes N2 to return N1?  You already have N1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess:

```
set.seed(2)
n <- 10
N1 <- letters[rbinom(n, size = 20, prob = 0.5)]
names(N1) <- seq(n)
N1
#   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10 
# "h" "k" "j" "h" "n" "n" "g" "l" "j" "j"
```

Having repeats makes it difficult to find a return function, since there is not a 1-to-1 mapping. However, if ...

```
ind <- sample(n)
ind
#  [1]  6  3  7  2  9  5  4  1 10  8
N2 <- N1[ind]
N2
#   6   3   7   2   9   5   4   1  10   8 
# "n" "j" "g" "k" "j" "n" "h" "h" "j" "l"
```

We have the same effect that you were doing before, except ...

```
N2[order(ind)]
#   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10 
# "h" "k" "j" "h" "n" "n" "g" "l" "j" "j" 
all(N1 == N2[order(ind)])
# [1] TRUE
```

This allows you to get a reverse mapping from some function on `N2`:

```
toupper(N2)[order(ind)]
#   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10 
# "H" "K" "J" "H" "N" "N" "G" "L" "J" "J"
```

regardless of whether you have an assured 1-to-1 mapping.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort, @r2evans.